# Second docker image is overriding the first image

Tags: docker, fluentd, docker-multi-stage-build

I am updating the solution worked for me here. if we want to run more than two processes in a single docker container, we can use supervisor approach like below

```
FROM clamav/clamav:1.1
RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor
RUN apk add <process2>
COPY supervisord.conf /etc
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:clamav]
command=<To-start-clamav>


[program:process2]
command=.<To-start-process2>
```

Comment: A container only runs a single process, so you'd almost always run these in two separate containers.

Comment: Got the point. The use-case i have  demands only one container to come up and having both the installations. I  tried installing second tool using RUN instructions but it didnt worked so i am left to do some kind of merging images if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The second `FROM` instructions is pulling a new image(fluentd) which delete the changes made in your first one(clamav).
If you want to create 2 images then you need 2 dockerfile.
And so split your file in two.

If you are planning on having only one image containing both applications, your dockerfile should look something like this:

```
FROM fluentd:v1.16.0-debian-1.0
COPY fluent.conf /fluentd/etc/
RUN apt install clamav clamav-daemon -y
COPY clamd.conf /etc/clamav

EXPOSE 3310/tcp
```

Comment: I want to create one image that will have both clamav and fluentd.

Comment: In that case you have to build it from one base (one FROM instruction) and install the other application using RUN instructions.

Comment: Thanks pgossa, i actually want to fetch both the images from dockerhub only. Please suggest if any template you have for that.

Comment: A docker images is created from one base image and then you add instructions which are used to create layers. It does not make sense in docker to merge image as it would means: merge layers from different base together, which is not possible.
Note that you can create your image and push it on dockerhub to reuse it on another system without having to build it.

Answer (score 0):

@pgossa, what about this one. maybe not a good approach as you mentioned but will it work? just a thought.

```
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.14-1 AS fluentd
COPY fluent.conf /fluentd/etc/

FROM clamav/clamav:1.1
COPY clamd.conf /etc/clamav
COPY --from=fluentd /fluentd /fluentd
EXPOSE 3310/tcp
```